# I am a beginner in FlashCS6. Coding ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

My Problem as stated

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 19', Frame 1, Line 23 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Boolean.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 19', Frame 1, Line 28 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Boolean.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 19', Frame 1, Line 33 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Boolean.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 19', Frame 1, Line 38 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Boolean.
```

My Code was Fine Until I add a mini button between frames because i cant find a tutorial putting a coding between. some say i need to put it in a new layer. im stuck myself. Please help!

```
    stop();

header_mc.home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);
header_mc.logo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);

function gohome (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1)
}

header_mc.about_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goabout);

function goabout (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2)
}

header_mc.image_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goimage);

function goimage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(3)
}

////////Button 1//////////
thumb1_btn.enabled=true.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetFirstImage)
function GetFirstImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(4)
}
////////Button 2//////////
thumb2_btn.enabled=true.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetSecondImage)
function GetSecondImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(5)
}
////////Button 3//////////
thumb3_btn.enabled=true.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetThirdImage)
function GetThirdImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(7)
}
////////Button 4//////////
thumb4_btn.enabled=true.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, GetForthImage)
function GetForthImage (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(6)
}

header_mc.contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gocontact);

function gocontact (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(7)
}

header_mc.demo_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, godemo);

function godemo (event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(8)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably, what you want to achieve is:

```
thumb4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gocontact);
```

not

```
thumb4_btn.enabled=true.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gocontact)
```

Only objects that implement IEventDispatcher have addEventListener method

Comment: If the `enabled` property should be set in addition to calling the function, that should happen on a separate line.